Is it possible to book a Nightjet with a connection and arbitrary layover?
I have been trying to plan my route from Hamburg to Bergamo via train.
My plan was to go to Milan via Basel: there's a direct connection (Nightjet sleeper) from Hamburg to Basel, and then another direct train from Basel to Milan.
I tried to book this as a single ticket on bahn.de, and I can select my desired route with a 4h layover in Basel to briefly check the city, stretch my legs and still arrive at my destination before the end of the 2nd day of travel.
Unfortunately, I can book the sleeper/couchette if I only select the route to Basel, but not if I try to make a single booking for my full itinerary.
Upon discovering this limitation with the bahn.de website, I decided to try to ask and book in person at a DB desk in Germany, once I finally arrived in Hamburg. By then unfortunately the normal couchette towards Basel was sold out, so I decided to opt instead for a Nightjet to Innsbruck which would then allow me to connect to Verona and Brescia.
I was about to book in person, when I realised that the price that the DB desk was quoting me was 90EUR higher than online. It seems that was because the couchette/mini-cabin NightJet option is only available online.
I then noticed that on nightjet.com it is actually possible to book a sleeper train with a connection before/after. But it's possible to choose only the connection immediately after, it's not possible to select a later train to allow more time for the change.
Once I realised that (and also, because I was already at the DB desk ready to pay with the cash that I brought expressly for the trip), I booked the cheaper couchette directly online, and the rest of my itinerary (via Verona) as a ticket from the DB desk.
Is there no other way to book this route?
What are the consequences of booking this way in case of delay/cancellation/disruption that might cause me to miss a connection?

In cases like this I have booked separate tickets but 4 hours between trains might mean that with a serious delay you miss the second train in which case the 'missed train' rules of the second train company count.

If I check the national page of bahn.de, the offers for the nightjet part are identical, no matter if I try to book to Basel or with a stopover to Milan.
